# My Wireless Network is not listed [hidden network]

Tags: wireless, 64-bit, dell, 12.10

My home wireless network is listed as hidden network and every time I log in, I have to connect it manually. It is not listed in wireless connection list. I can only connect it with selecting "Connect to Hidden Wireless Network" option. I didn't have any problems with 12.04.

My laptop model is : Dell Inspiron n5110

OS: 12.10 - 64 bit

**Hardware Information:**

```
sudo lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:1c1e] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df5] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [8086:008a] (rev 34)
0b:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Texas Instruments TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller [104c:8241] (rev 02)

sudo lshw -class network

*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 24:b6:fd:21:eb:86
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:55 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f3204000-f3204fff memory:f3200000-f3203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 4c:eb:42:13:25:e5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-17-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.2.86 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:58 memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 (rev 34)
0b:00.0 USB controller: Texas Instruments TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller (rev 02)
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: ok updated first post, added hardware details.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I should warn you hidden wireless network has proved to be even more vulnerable than normal wireless connection and the manual evaluation is there for a reason. Hence I suggest you should reconfigure your router to be not hidden.

Of course there is a workaround to avoid the annoying manual evaluation in case you insist using hidden connection. Just open nm-connection-editor and **clear** the check box on 'Available to all users'. Then network-manager should be able to auto connect.

Comment: clear check on "Available to all users" didn't work for me. (It still doesn't connect automatically) My wireless network isn't hidden; I've two other PCs, they're NOT accepted as hidden network.

Answer (score 0):

Does your network SSID appears if you do a manual scan ?

1. Find out your wireless interface name

   > iwconfig

The output should be like

```
$ iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"..."  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:... GHz  Access Point: ...
```

2. Scan for networks and show only founded SSIDs by (replace wlan0 with your interface name)

   > sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID

The output should be like

```
SSID: ed...
SSID: TUB...
SSID: ed...
...
```