# Can't connect to wifi in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, internet-connection, version-upgrade

Since upgrading to 12.10 while it was in beta, I have been unable to connect to wifi, which I was able to do while using 12.04. My laptop is an Acer extensa 5635z.

Comment: having same problem.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/204088/my-wireless-network-is-not-listed-hidden-network

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **fwcutter** would help

To install fwcutter:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install fwcutter
```

It mainly works for BCM hardware

You can also install fwcutter legacy driver if you are unable find them.  Unfortunately you will need to google it

Comment: pls help with guide to getting fwcutter legacy driver as was unable to install it. aare@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install fwcutter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fwcutter